# How to set resistance measurements of particle layers in a resistivity cell, using an electrometer?

Tags: resistance, resistivity

I am new to the use of electrometers as I come from the totally different environment of analogue experiments in fluids. Although I am familiar with the electrical measurements concepts, I am struggling in getting resistance measurements.

I have a resistivity cell for measuring the volume resistance of powders and liquids (built by us, photo below, but very similar to this one: https://www.electrotechsystems.com/products/electrostatic-instumentation/resistance-probes-clamps/volume-resistivity-test-cells-for-liquids-and-powders/). The concept is to use known volumes of particles of different compositions, and measure their resistivity.
[image: Resistivity chamber, and 6514 in background]

I have for the measures a 6514 electrometer (https://www.tek.com/en/products/keithley/low-level-sensitive-and-specialty-instruments/electrometers), that I understand uses a constant current for calculating a voltage drop depending on an unknown resistance, and using the Ohm law calculates the resistance, that I can then use for the volume resistivity knowing the dimension of my cell.

My though was to connect the HI and LO of the electrometer to my cell, and the ground to the metal enclosure that isolates the main cell. However, when in resistance mode, my value reading oscillates constantly and not in a negligible way (e.g., from 0.38 kΩ to XX GΩ or similar, going up and small steps down all the time but constantly going up). This using a compacted layer of particles for which I need to measure the resistivity as test. I cannot figure out if the issue is in using a constant current of the 6514 here, or is there something I am missing? Should I instead connect a power supply to the chamber, and provide a voltage to the cell, and measure the resistivity based on the provided voltage? But then how should I do the connection? There are some hints on the 6514 website (https://www.tek.com/de/support/faqs/how-do-i-connect-my-electrometer-voltage-source-make-high-resistance-measurement-my-dev) but also in this case I cannot get more-or-less stable value, using a GWInstek GPW4323 power supply which is what I have available now.

Comment: The electrical bit, measure current, measure voltage, is the easy bit. The tough bit is the physical stuff, contacts, between electrodes and grains, between grains and grains, what pressure to use, humidity, vibration, environmental contamination, are all nightmares.

Comment: Yes, contacts, shielding, etc is something I am trying to address now, and will probably add shielded BNCs to the chamber, and a shorter lead from the electrometer to it, using shielded BNCs as well. Hopefully I'll start to see some credible values using low resistivity material such as copper or similar.